# How to insert date range to mysql in individual rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm, planning to insert many row in my MySQL my code is to insert a row for each date and i have a date-start and date-end so for each date i want to insert 1 row
please help me with inserting in my Wamp server using Php MySQL

i want to insert all the dates between my datestart and dateend individually can you help me with this thanks

Comment: "...here is my code". What code? All I see is some type of pseudocode, if that.  Please clarify.

Comment: sorry my bad ... all i have i a form that has a datestart and dateend  and i want to insert  it in my wamp server  all the dates between the datestart and date end individualy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to insert multiple rows at one time in mysql you need to add a comma after your first set of data

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","mysqluser","mysqlpw","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tablename(`uid`, `firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('15', 'James', 'thompson'),('25', 'Michael', 'Bagwell')");

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

for each additional row add another ,('id', 'first', 'last')

since your request has quite changed here is an update for the dates

```
<?php
$startdate = strtotime($_POST["startdate"]);
$enddate = strtotime($_POST["enddate"]);
$sdate = date('Y-m-d',$startdate);
$edate = date('Y-m-d',$enddate);
$datediff = $sdate - $edate;
$countdays = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename(`incdate`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES ('" . $sdate . "', 'data', 'data')"

for ($i = 1; $i < $countdays; $i++) {
    $sdate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $query .= "('" . $sdate . "', 'data', 'data')"
}

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con, $query);

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

not tested but it should work, it finds the difference in your inputted start and end date in days then adds each day to the query as appropriate - once completed it runs the query

Comment: yeah thanks... but how can i do that using post method in my form

Comment: I am editing to change to your new request

Comment: just remember to accept as answer and mark as useful if it helps